# Append a nd numpy array into existing csv file

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, numpy-ndarray

I have a csv file and i tried to append to it a numpy array with the shape (1,538,341).

I have tried 2 different approches :

1) convert the np to pandas and then save it to the csv.
2) use of the np.totext

in both cases I got an error

can someone help me?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you put up a small sample instance of the csv contents and the array? Moreover, have you tried converting the numpy array to two dimensions?

Comment: Hi,thank you for your quick response actually i have np array with the shape (650,538,341) but I thought to loop throw the csv file and append each (1,538,341) to the file with a " " separtor between the appends.                                                             in each iteraton i will have 538 row and 341 cols/  can i  reshape (1,538,341) to *538,341) and then do what i want?

Comment: Yes, pretty easily using np.reshape. So if np.shape(d) = (1, 538, 341), then assign d2 = np.reshape(d, (538, 341)). d2 is the required array. Then you can use append the file however you want. I'd use pandas as it makes the whole thing a lot easier.